# Should CNN layers come before Bi-LSTM or after?

Tags: keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a Univariate Time Series forecasting model. The current architecture is looking
like this :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
```

Then I tried the following, which places all CNN layers before Bi-LSTM layers (but doesn't work):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_steps_out))
```

The latest implementation doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions of fixing this ? Another question I had was, is there a one method approach to decide if CNN should come before Bi-LSTM of vice-versa ?

Comment: The latest implementation doesn't work because u use Flatten and u are destroying 3D format which is a constraint for LSTM layers

Comment: I removed Flatten(), but it's not working yet, do I need to possibly ensure the input shape is reshaped ?

Comment: If u are interested I can provide u an example... I need u give me your X and y shapes

Comment: Thanks @MarcoCerliani. Just after splitting the dataset into samples, I have the following: X.shape, y.shape = ((45176, 30), (45176, 15)). After reshaping from [samples, timesteps] into [samples, timesteps, features], I get -> X.shape, y.shape
((45176, 30, 1), (45176, 15, 1)). There is only one feature. The reshaped data is fed into the Neural Network. I have also noticed that I need to apply this reshaping instead in order to get the model to fit : X.shape, y.shape
((45176, 30, 1), (45176, 15)). Not sure why the network expects (y.shape) to have a 2D.

Comment: I added an example below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your network receives as input sequences and output sequences so u need to take care of dimensionality. to do this you have to play with padding in convolutional layers and with pooling operation. you also need to set return_sequences=True in your last LSTM cell (you are predicting a sequence). In the example below I use your network with padding and I delate flattening which destroys the 3D dimensionality

you can apply Convolution before or after LSTM. the best way to do this is to try both and evaluate the performance with a trustable validation set

## CNN + LSTM

```
n_sample = 100
n_steps_in, n_steps_out, n_features = 30, 15, 1
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, n_steps_in, n_features))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, n_steps_out, n_features))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same',
                 input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()

model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

## LSTM + CNN

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True), 
                 input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('adam', 'mse')
model.summary()

model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to use an extra layer "model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))" just before the very last layer, model.add(Dense(1)) ? I see this as an extra layer that may help with a better model generalization, but do you feel that it is indeed recommended ?

Comment: In the case of a pure CNN model (without any LSTM layers), is this a good approach ? model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu')) # ------> Extra layer
model.add(Dense(1))

Comment: Adding extra dense layer can be good but with caution... if u exceed you go easily in overfitting. In general, if u would like to make a variation in your model, I suggest u to have a validation schema and evaluate the changes on them

Answer (score 2):

May I know what exactly you mean by saying it doesn't seem to work?

Because I'd rather you perform any convolutions before the LSTM as you've done in the second approach. But here are a few things to note.

First, you are only supposed to return the sequences from an LSTM layer, only when the next layer is also LSTM:

```
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20)))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Second, you could try using GlobalAveragePooling1D instead of MaxPooling1D as the latter takes all features into account (an important factor to note compared to classifying images, for instance):

```
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D(pool_size=2))
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable inputs, I get this error after trying to fit the neural network -> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 (this is what I meant by saying it doesn't seem to work).

Comment: I also observe something quite strange. With the following: model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features), return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True))), I am able to fit the model successfully. However if I remove 'return_sequences=True' from the second BiDirectional LSTM layer, I get -> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_5: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2.